# How to insert a picture into Excel at a specified cell position with VBA

Tags: excel, image, vba, insert

I'm adding ".jpg" files to my Excel sheet with the code below :

```
'Add picture to excel
xlApp.Cells(i, 20).Select
xlApp.ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(picPath).Select
'Calgulate new picture size
With xlApp.Selection.ShapeRange
    .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    .Width = 75
    .Height = 100
End With
'Resize and make printable
With xlApp.Selection
    .Placement = 1 'xlMoveAndSize
    '.Placement = 2 'xlMove
    '.Placement = 3 'xlFreeFloating
    .PrintObject = True
End With
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong but it doesn't get inserted into the right cell, so what should I do to put this picture into a specified cell in Excel?

Comment: You can set the picture's TopLeftCell property.

Comment: yea after long hours of programming sometimes things as easy as this become a big deal you know..

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try this:

```
With xlApp.ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PicPath)
    With .ShapeRange
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Width = 75
        .Height = 100
    End With
    .Left = xlApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 20).Left
    .Top = xlApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 20).Top
    .Placement = 1
    .PrintObject = True
End With
```

It's better not to .select anything in Excel, it is usually never necessary and slows down your code.

Comment: For people landing here. Different versions of Excel handle this request differently, Excel 2007 will insert the picture as an object, ie embed it in the workbook. Excel 2010 will insert it as a link, which is bad times if you plan on sending it to anyone. You need to change the insert to specify that it is embedded: Insert(Filename:= <path>, LinkToFile:= False, SaveWithDocument:= True)

Answer (score 8):

Looking at posted answers I think this code would be also an alternative for someone. Nobody above used `.Shapes.AddPicture` in their code, only `.Pictures.Insert()`

```
Dim myPic As Object
Dim picpath As String

picpath = "C:\Users\photo.jpg" 'example photo path

Set myPic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(picpath, False, True, 20, 20, -1, -1)

With myPic
    .Width = 25
    .Height = 25
    .Top = xlApp.Cells(i, 20).Top 'according to variables from correct answer
    .Left = xlApp.Cells(i, 20).Left
    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
End With
```

I'm working in Excel 2013. Also realized that You need to fill all the parameters in `.AddPicture`, because of error "Argument not optional". Looking at this You may ask why I set `Height` and `Width` as -1, but that doesn't matter cause of those parameters are set underneath between `With` brackets.

Hope it may be also useful for someone :)

Answer (score 6):

If it's simply about inserting and resizing a picture, try the code below.

For the specific question you asked, the property TopLeftCell returns the range object related to the cell where the top left corner is parked. To place a new image at a specific place, I recommend creating an image at the "right" place and registering its top and left properties values of the dummy onto double variables.

Insert your Pic assigned to a variable to easily change its name. The Shape Object will have that same name as the Picture Object.

```
Sub Insert_Pic_From_File(PicPath as string, wsDestination as worksheet)
    Dim Pic As Picture, Shp as Shape
    Set Pic = wsDestination.Pictures.Insert(FilePath)
    Pic.Name = "myPicture"
    'Strongly recommend using a FileSystemObject.FileExists method to check if the path is good before executing the previous command
    Set Shp = wsDestination.Shapes("myPicture")
    With Shp
        .Height = 100
        .Width = 75
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue  'Put this later so that changing height doesn't change width and vice-versa)
        .Placement = 1
        .Top = 100
        .Left = 100
    End with
End Sub
```

Good luck!

Comment: Shouldn't FilePath be PicPath? Or visa versa?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, of all I recommend that the pictures are in the same folder as the workbook.
You need to enter some codes in the Worksheet_Change procedure of the worksheet. For example, we can enter the following codes to add the image that with the same name as the value of cell in column A to the cell in column D:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim pic As Picture
If Intersect(Target, [A:A]) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo son

For Each pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
    If Not Application.Intersect(pic.TopLeftCell, Range(Target.Offset(0, 3).Address)) Is Nothing Then
        pic.Delete
    End If
Next pic

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Target.Value & ".jpg").Select
Selection.Top = Target.Offset(0, 2).Top
Selection.Left = Target.Offset(0, 3).Left
Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
Selection.ShapeRange.Height = Target.Offset(0, 2).Height
Selection.ShapeRange.Width = Target.Offset(0, 3).Width
son:

End Sub
```

With the codes above, the picture is sized according to the cell it is added to.

Details and sample file here : [Vba Insert image to cell](https://eksi30.com/insert-picture-in-cell-according-to-cell-value/)

[image]

Comment: Yea years ago those (top, left) properties was the issue. Ty for the different approach though.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on a system that ran on a PC and Mac and was battling to find code that worked for inserting pictures on both PC and Mac.  This worked for me so hopefully someone else can make use of it!

Note: the strPictureFilePath and strPictureFileName variables need to be set to valid PC and Mac paths Eg

For PC: strPictureFilePath  = "E:\Dropbox\" and strPictureFileName = "TestImage.jpg" and with Mac: strPictureFilePath  = "Macintosh HD:Dropbox:" and strPictureFileName = "TestImage.jpg"

Code as Follows:

```
    On Error GoTo ErrorOccured

    shtRecipeBrowser.Cells(intDestinationRecipeRowCount, 1).Select

    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Trim(strPictureFilePath & strPictureFileName)).Select

    Selection.ShapeRange.Left = shtRecipeBrowser.Cells(intDestinationRecipeRowCount, 1).Left
    Selection.ShapeRange.Top = shtRecipeBrowser.Cells(intDestinationRecipeRowCount, 1).Top + 10
    Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 130
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested both @SWa and @Teamothy solution. I did not find the `Pictures.Insert` Method in the Microsoft Documentations and feared some compatibility issues. So I guess, the older `Shapes.AddPicture` Method should work on all versions. But it is slow!

```
On Error Resume Next
'
' first and faster method (in Office 2016)
'
    With ws.Pictures.Insert(Filename:=imageFileName, LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = destRange.Width
            .height = destRange.height '222
        End With
        .Left = destRange.Left
        .Top = destRange.Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
        .Name = imageName
    End With
'
' second but slower method (in Office 2016)
'

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Dim myPic As Shape
    Set myPic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=imageFileName, _
            LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
            Left:=destRange.Left, Top:=destRange.Top, Width:=-1, height:=destRange.height)

    With myPic.OLEFormat.Object.ShapeRange
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Width = destRange.Width
        .height = destRange.height '222
    End With
End If
```

Comment: `Pictures.Insert` is defined in `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. So therefore in VBA one should use the `Shapes.AddPicture` method.