# Creating an excel library (DLL for excel)?

Tags: excel, vba, dll

I am working on a project within excel and am starting prepare my document for future performance related problems. The excel file contains large amounts of data and large amounts of images which are all in sets, ie, 40 images belong to one function of the program, another 50 belong to another etc... and only one set of them is used at a time.

This file is only going to get bigger as the number of jobs/functions it has to handle increase. Now, I could just make multiple excel files and let the user choose which one is appropriate for the job but it is requested that this is all done from one file.

Baring this in mind, I started thinking about methods of creating such a large file whilst keeping its performance levels high and had an idea which I am not sure is possible or not. This is to have multiple protected workbooks each one containing the information for each job "set" and a main workbook which accesses these files depending on the user inputs. This will result in many excel files which take time to download initially but whilst being used should eliminate the low performance issues as the computer only has to access a subset of these files.

From what I understand this is sort of like what DLL's are for but I am not sure if the same can be done by excel and if possible would the performance increase be significant?

If anyone has any other suggestions or elegant solutions on how this can be done please let me know.

Comment: Could you not use a database, with the correct data being pulled in by a query from VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than saving data such as images in the excel file itself, write your macro to load the appropriate images from files and have your users select which routine to run.  This way, you load only files you need.  If your data is text / numbers, you can store it in a CSV or, if your data gets very large, use a Microsoft Access database and retrieve the data using the ADODB library.

Inserting Images: [How to insert a picture into Excel at a specified cell position with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936646/how-to-insert-a-picture-into-excel-at-a-specified-cell-position-with-vb6)

More on using ADODB: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx