# Export Image to Excel in Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

This is the first time I write in this place.
I was looking for a solution everywhere and I could not find it. I do not know if it can be done or not.

The theme is like this:
I have a json where one of the data it contains is an image. I need to export that json to an excel, where each data goes to a cell. Therefore, I need to be able to insert that image into one of the cells.

Is it possible to do this? Keep in mind that it is for a mobile app offline, so it should be in javascript and client side.

Many thanks!
Greetings.

Comment: The code basically iterates a json. For each iteration, you should generate a new row in excel. In that row, a field is an image. The question is how do I make that image look in excel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a JS library to create excel. I haven't tried it though.
https://github.com/stephenliberty/excel-builder.js
However, it should be fairly trivial to loop through your JSON and create a CSV file, which will ultimately open in excel.  That might work better depending on your needs.

But to be clear, when you say holds an image, do you mean a link to an image, or a base64 text of an image?  The latter would be huge and probably break excel in some way.

Comment: My application works completely offline. Therefore, I could not have a link to an image. The image is text in base64. My question is how do I do in Excel to see an image in base 64. Because now I can only see the text in the cell.

Comment: Oh, funny I am doing the exact same thing for a cordova app right now. I am reading this guide. http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/150/how-to-create-an-image-file-from-a-base64-string-on-the-device-with-cordova  Maybe it will help you?  The other way I read was to put the image to a canvas, then get back the blob, which can then be written to a file.  I can't post code though because I haven't actually done it yet, just reading about it.

Comment: But can a blob image be inserted into an excel cell?

Comment: Not directly.  You'd have to save it to a file, then do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936646/how-to-insert-a-picture-into-excel-at-a-specified-cell-position-with-vba

If you have access to add macros to the excel file, you can make this a lot easier on yourself.  Then you just use an excel template with macros.