# Excel VBA Userform Picture to worksheet cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question. Is it possible to safe a picure from a workbook userform to a second workbook into a cell.

My code creates a new workbook with a new sheet named newsheet.
There I want to insert certain pictures on cell value into the range I am in right now. So far I have something like this:

```
lrow = newsheet.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).rows
for i = 1 to lrow
 if newsheet.range("C" & i) <> "" then 
   'search for name of userfrom, the userfrom name is the same as cell value
     'and insert that picture from that userform into "C" & i
  end if
  next i
```

Comment: I think it is.  Record a macro of you doing this, then inspect that code, and look at the object that you want to copy the image from, is this an image on a form, your question doesn't specify what control in the form it's coming from.

Comment: I inserted the picture directly into the userform so I could refere to it like: userform1.picture.

Recording macro does not work as far as I know in terms of refering from the value of the cell to userform name.

Comment: Exactly, you can learn from that macro how to start coding it

Comment: Not sure how you want to this.
lets imagine userform1 is the string in cell c1 then I want the picture from the userform1 to show up in that cell. No idea how to use the record macro option to do this.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936646/how-to-insert-a-picture-into-excel-at-a-specified-cell-position-with-vba)

Comment: yes, I have. The problem is if write filename:= userform1.picture an error occures which says file not found.

Comment: Please provide your entire code - The main part of what you're trying is missing.
That said, do you know on forehand how many pictures there are on the userform(s), what the name(s) of the picture control(s) are and what the form name is going to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to copy the bitmap straight from the `UserForm` to the Worksheet. Worksheet doesn't have `Image` objects the way the form has and when adding pictures (either in a Shape, or using `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert` method, the parameter taken is a filename.

That said, you can create a temporary file to save the picture you have in the UserForm and use that file to insert the picture at the location you need.

I created a workbook that has a userform named "TestForm" with one Image control named "Image1" on it.

The following code in a regular module does the trick:

```
Sub Test()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim formname As String
Dim tempfile As String

'Create new workbook:
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

'Setting form name in new sheet. Using row 1 in this example.
ws.Range("C1").Value = "TestForm"

'Retrieve the "found" value
formname = ws.Range("C1").Value

'Save the picture and get the location:
tempfile = SavePictureFromForm(formname)

'Navigate to the correct location, since we need it selected for Pictures.Insert
ws.Activate
Range("C1").Select
'Add the picture to the sheet:
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert tempfile

'Clean up the file system:
DeleteTempPicture tempfile
End Sub
```

Function that saves the picture from the form, provided it's in an Image control named "Image1". Also returns the location to the routine above:

```
Function SavePictureFromForm(formname As String) As String
Dim tempfilepath As String
Dim tempfilename As String

'Location + filename:
tempfilepath = "C:\Temp\"
tempfilename = "temppicture.jpg"

'Get the correct userform:
Set Obj = VBA.UserForms.Add(formname)

'Save the picture and return it's location:
SavePicture Obj.Image1.Picture, tempfilepath & tempfilename
SavePictureFromForm = tempfilepath & tempfilename

End Function
```

Delete the temporary file:

```
Public Sub DeleteTempPicture(filename As String)
'Delete the temporary file throught FSO:
Dim FSO As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
With FSO
    .DeleteFile filename
End With
Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note that the above has **ZERO** error handling. If the Name of the form in the cell is invalid, it'll crash. If the form doesn't have an "Image1" control of type image, it'll crash, if you pass an invalid filename to the deletion routine, it'll crash.

However - it does do what you mentioned: Create new workbook, add the picture from a userform in the original workbook to the new workbook (on sheet 1) based on the userform name. Since the question isn't more detailed and your exact use case is unknown, this should be more than sufficient to get you up and running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is working as well, but I got my code up and running from another website. This code runs with API calls rather than a temporary file. 

The reason why I don't like the temporary file is that I need to hand out my macro to lots of people with different computers and settings. So finding a proper temporary path is not easy.

I now that my methode has zero error handling, but it is not needed as the user is only allowed to insert 5 different names into the cell which all have a corresponding userform.

Comment: @webjoh That's another (probably better) alternative indeed - I tried to stick to supported methods in VBA, without accessing any other libraries. Glad it's solved.