# Excel, add or remove by copying data from previous table

Tags: excel, vba

Im looking to add rows to table (formatting, data and pictures) which mimics previous data in the sheet.

Basically column ABC holds data and column D+E holds pictures. The data/pictures has an extra row below with description. The entire thing is formatted with thick borders.

Basically I would like to achieve add rows button and an remove rows button which adds or removes above.

How would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a lot more specifics in your question, I would suggest screenshot, too.

The border formatting sounds completely aesthetic; you may be able to achieve your goal simply by formatting everything as a table... Home -> Format as Table

This is how you can progressively insert rows using VBA:

```
Sub AddRow()

Dim count As Integer

ActiveSheet.Select

count = 1

Rows(count).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown

count = count + 1


End Sub
```

Here is good content on assigning images to cells:

[How to insert a picture into Excel at a specified cell position with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936646/how-to-insert-a-picture-into-excel-at-a-specified-cell-position-with-vba)