# Excel vba insert picture into cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have previous version (not office 365) so i dont have the built in function =image.
I have wrriten a code that insert a picture but not in spcific cell and i dont why.
Second question is how can i format the code to be a function like =image and not a macro.
Code:

```
Sub insertimage()
Dim path,cell as string
Cell = activecell.address
Path = application.getopenfilename()
Set image = activesheet.pictures.insert(path)
Image.top = range(cell).top
Image.left = range(cell).left
End sub
```

Comment: Using the search function: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=VBA+Add+image brings you for example this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68616504/7599798

Comment: I edit my question to be more specific, thanks.