# How to save inserted pictures in excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to insert some pictures that are saved on my desktop to an excel file.

I found that some online codes worked well. But it seemed that those inserted pictures were not saved with the documents - the inserted pictures won't be displayed when I opened the file on another computer. I am wondering how I should tweak the codes so it can save the inserted pictures within the excel? If possible with VBA, how to adjust the inserted pictures to their 50% dimensions? I am completely new to VBA. Sorry for this basic question.

```
Sub add_pictures_R2()
Dim i%, ppath$
For i = 2 To 145   
    ' file name at column A
    ppath = "C:\Users\myname\output\" & CStr(Cells(i, 1).Value) & ".png"
    If Len(Dir(ppath)) Then
        With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(ppath)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 75
            .Height = 300
        End With
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Left
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
    End If
    
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: See the comment under this previous answer  -https://stackoverflow.com/a/12936911/478884

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for sharing the link. Based on the comments from the link, including `With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Filename:=ppath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)` should solve my issue. But it turns out that it will cause an error called "Run-time error 488. Named argument not found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from Jimmypop at [mrexcel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/). It worked.

```
Sub add_pictures_R2()
        Const folderPath As String = "C:\Users\YANG\output\"
        Dim r As Long
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With ActiveSheet
            For r = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                If Dir(folderPath & .Cells(r, "A").Value & ".png") <> vbNullString Then
                    .Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=folderPath & .Cells(r, "A").Value & ".png", _
                                       LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, _
                                       Left:=ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 10).Left, Top:=ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 10).Top, Width:=.Cells(r, "C").Width, Height:=.Cells(r, "C").Height
                
                Else
                    .Cells(r, "B").Value = "Not found"
                End If
                DoEvents
            Next
        End With
            Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)
    For Each s In myDocument.Shapes
        Select Case s.Type
        Case msoLinkedPicture, msoPicture
            s.ScaleHeight 0.5, msoTrue
            s.ScaleWidth 0.5, msoTrue
        Case Else
    '       Do Nothing
        End Select
    Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            MsgBox "Done"
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do either, edit the path of the file to go along with your excel file or you could embed it. For embedding I would look at this.
https://danny.fyi/embedding-and-accessing-a-file-in-excel-with-vba-and-ole-objects-4d4e7863cfff

Its a bit messy but you would achieve what you want to do with at least the file being in the document and not trying to transfer everything with it.

Comment: [link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer) are not accepted on StackOverflow. Please copy the relevant code snippets, just what is needed to answer the question. You can read that link for a full discussion on why.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using `Shapes.AddPicture`)

```vb
Sub add_pictures_R2()
    'Note - type identifiers such as `S`, `%` are very outdated...
    Dim i As Long, ppath As String, ws As Worksheet, c As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet  'use a specific/explicit sheet reference
    For i = 2 To 145
        ppath = "C:\Users\myname\output\" & CStr(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value) & ".png"
    
        Set c = ws.Cells(i, 10) 'insertion point
        'passing -1 to Width/Height preserves original size
        With ws.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=ppath, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
                                  savewithdocument:=msoTrue, _
                                  Left:=c.Left, Top:=c.Top, Width:=-1, Height:=-1)
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Placement = xlMove
            .Height = .Height / 2        'size to 50%
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting your code! Unfortunately, it didn't work. I got an error message " Ru-time error `1004`: Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: On which line ?  Maybe check your file paths

Comment: I cannot tell. How can I find which line caused the error?

Comment: When it errors, click "Debug"