# Loading Image from URL in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I have a gigantic excel spread sheet with over 20,000 URL's. It would be very inefficient of me to click on each link to check the image. Instead I was wondering if I could take the url from one cell and load the image into a different cell. This of course would have to be a loop as I have so many images to load. So far I found a thread on this already but I have no idea how to implement this code.

[How to get images to appear in Excel given image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312710/how-to-get-images-to-appear-in-excel-given-image-url)

If someone could tell me how to use this code that would be great and you will also save my sanity. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your Excel sheet is open, press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>   (Edit: Not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>)
This will open the Visual Basic editor. From there, locate the project explorer to the left side of the screen. It should appear something like `VBAProject (YourWorkBookName.XLS)`
right click it and select Insert -> Module.

You should see a blank white space for you to put code in. Just paste the code you found from the other post, but make sure you paste it inside a SUB definition , like this:

```
Sub AnyNameCanBeChoosen()

   ' Paste your code Here

End Sub
```

Then press F5 to execute your code.

Comment: Awesome thanks, but what does this mean.

Run-time error '1004':

Unable to get the Insert property of the Pictures class