# Excel CSV Convert HTML IMG SRC to actual image

Tags: html, image, excel, csv, src

I am hoping there is an easy way to do this but am at a loss.  It's a hard subject to search on so I apologize if it has been covered previously.  couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

What I have is a MySQL table.  In that table there is a field which has a full image src which was scraped from a website like so:

```
<img src="http://whatever.com/image.jpg" height="30" width="120"/>
```

Right now I have the entire table being exported into a CSV file which is then opened and manipulated in Excel but it only has this image link in text format.

I am hoping there is an easy way to say save to Excel format xls/xlsx, then reopen the file and it shows the actual image rather than just the text that was pulled from the database.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Im almost sure you cant have images in CSV, and especially not from a url..

There might be a way to have it in base64 saved in the SQL database although **THIS IS NOT ADVISED** From there you might be able to configure something to render the image but it would be horribly awkward.

Even at that im 99% certain you cant display the image in CSV.

Edit: just to confirm CSV is text base only. :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

You could get Excel to read the image with creating a sub in a worksheet.
Paste the code below in.

```
Dim url_column As Range
Dim image_column As Range

Set url_column = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("A")
Set image_column = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("B")

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To url_column.Cells.Count

  With image_column.Worksheet.Pictures.Insert(url_column.Cells(i).Value)
    .Left = image_column.Cells(i).Left
    .Top = image_column.Cells(i).Top
    image_column.Cells(i).EntireRow.RowHeight = .Height
  End With

Next
```

Credit and ref to the EXCEPTIONAL answer : [How to get images to appear in Excel given image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312710/how-to-get-images-to-appear-in-excel-given-image-url)

Comment: I know it can't display the image in the CSV format.  I hoping there is code that excel can read from an xls/xlsx file from the URL.