# Simple Visual basic If for images

Tags: excel, vba

I think it's too easy, but I'm just new in visual basic and I'm having problems solving this.

`If a1 => 1 then`
    in `b1` show `green.jpg`

`If a1 = 0 then`
    in `b1` show `red.jpg`

`Image.FromFile`, `LoadPicture`? How do I reference it in cell `b1`?

Comment: `Image.FromFile, LoadPicture?` - [`Pictures.Insert`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6312837/11683)

Comment: thanks. I read that before, by for now its not simple enought for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a picture into Excel at a specified cell position with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936646/how-to-insert-a-picture-into-excel-at-a-specified-cell-position-with-vba)

Comment: I know how to insert the image, the thing i need it's the control to change between two images (in b1 cell) depending on result on (a1 cell).