# Load an image from URL with POST

Tags: excel, vba, image, post

I need to load an image by calling an API and passing a JSON string via POST. The API returns a binary PNG image.

There are answers for loading an image from URL and sending a HTTP POST request, but not the two together.

[How to get images to appear in Excel given image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312710/how-to-get-images-to-appear-in-excel-given-image-url)

[How can I send an HTTP POST request to a server from Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba)

update:
Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub LoadQR()

Dim d As Byte
JSON = Range("C5").Value
 

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Url = "https://xxxxxxx/xxxx/api/qr/v1/gen"
objHTTP.Open "POST", Url, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"

objHTTP.send JSON
 
    ' Put response data into a file.
    Open "qr.png" For Binary As #1
    d = objHTTP.ResponseText
    Put #1, 1, d
    Close
    
    ' Load the data file as a picture.
    Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)
    myDocument.Shapes.AddPicture _
    "qr.png", _
    True, True, 500, 100, 70, 70
End Sub
```

Getting type mismatch because API response is actually binary, but `objHTTP.ResponseText` is a string.. any advice?

Comment: _I need to load an image_ - load into where ?

Comment: You could save the image from the POST response body, but it's unclear exactly what you want to do with it...

Comment: @CDP1802 , load the image anywhere in the sheet... just display it and be able to print it. It is actually a QR code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
Sub LoadQR()

Dim d() As Byte
JSON = Range("C5").Value
 

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Url = "https://xxxxxx/api/qr/v1/gen"
objHTTP.Open "POST", Url, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"

objHTTP.send JSON

    Open "qr.png" For Binary As #1
    d = objHTTP.ResponseBody
    Put #1, 1, d
    Close
    

    Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)
    myDocument.Shapes.AddPicture _
    "qr.png", _
    True, True, 450, 40, 200, 200

End Sub
```